# First character disappearing in ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

Why does this code print the char, without first character?? It says `ocalhost` instead of `localhost`. Grateful for help.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main ()  {    
int b = 0;
char * pch;
int stringLength = 0;
char textRead[50];
ifstream infile("config.ini", ios::in | ios::binary);            
if(!infile) {
            cout << "ERROR: config.ini not found!\n";
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
}

infile >> textRead;
stringLength = strlen(textRead);
pch=strchr(textRead,'"');
while(pch != NULL) {
          infile.seekg(pch-textRead-1);
          infile >> textRead;
          pch = strchr(pch+1,'"');
}
cout << textRead;
infile.close();
```

Comment: Impossible to tell without the contents of `config.ini`.

Comment: Why are you writing code to parse INI files at all? You're clearly using Windows, so call [`GetPrivateProfileString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724353.aspx) to get the INI values you need.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your while loop you call:

```
  infile >> textRead;
  pch = strchr(pch+1,'"');
```

When you try to run `strchr` in the second line, it's still referring back to the previous string you had in `textRead` NOT the most recently extracted word.

Unfortunately I can't deduce what you're actually trying to do so I can't offer suggestions on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at the contents of `config.ini`, since you didn't provide it, but it looks like the `ifstream` is reading just fine.  put a `cout << textRead << endl;` after your `infile >> textRead;` to check.  This is what I'm using for `config.ini`:

```
localhost = "foo"
```

Your logic with `seekg` and friends seems broken, though.  `seekg` isn't meant to be used to support parsing (in your case, skipping quotes); it's meant to skip over large chunks of file when needed so you don't waste time reading it in.  Honestly, I'm not sure what you're doing since `pch-textRead-1` could be -1 if the first character is a quote.

Another thing is that `infile >> textRead;` does not read a line, it reads a word, and discards leading whitespace.

For the record, I omitted

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

since it isn't needed.